# HTML - how to rotate back and forth, like a radar towards your and away from you 2.5D

Tags: css, html, image, image-rotation

I have a requirement, that needs to **rotate an image with some realistic sense - on a skewed horizontal plane with eye level**, imagine a spinning flying disc or helicopter blades.

By that I mean, (not a flat rotation like a spinner) but something that gets bigger when it its facing your disappears as it spins back - on a skewed horizontal plane with eye level.

objective is to get a realistic look with an icon or an image, where it looks like its rotating in 2.5D with HTML

1. Can this done with HTML5 simply, with out a canvas.
2. Can you share an example with either canvas or straight HTML5 trickery

Comment: HTML5 is a markup language. You can't make anything rotate by tags alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in CSS3 using a 3D transform:

```
transform: rotateX(45deg);
```

And on the container:

```
perspective: 500px;
```

Experiment with the exact values to get the effect you want.